# displaying recent comments outside loop without plugin

Tags: loop, comments

So I wanted to display the 10 most recent comments from my blog onto my homepage.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?
preferably without using a plugin if possible...

thank you.

Comment: I assume you were also looking for a solution without using a widget as well...

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with [`get_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments).

```
<?php
$comments = get_comments(array(
    'number'      => 10, // 10 comments
    'status'      => 'approve', // only approved comments
    'post_status' => 'publish', // only on published posts
));

// do stuff with $comments
```

You can see how the core itself does this in the [recent comments widget](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L682).